# What can be the url to run the extended ratings functionality

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.5, magento-1.6

I would like to get the ratings of products (out of magento) when I give the category ID and result should be in JSON format. I would like to get the JSON data just in the browser page.For this I have extended Rating.php located at app/code/core/mage/Rating/Model/Rating.php

According to the inchoo site, I have just copied and pasted the model file to app/code/local/mynamespace/appname/Model/Rating.php. I have created an config.xml file in the app/code/local/mynamespace/appname/etc/config.xml and also an xml at app/etc/modules.

In the site they told to add the line of 'var_dump(get_class($this)); exit();' at the function required. But I try the url many ways to get the ratings, But no use... The files are as folows:

Rating.php

```
<?php

class mnamespace_appname_Model_Rating extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    /**
     * rating entity codes
     *
     */
    const ENTITY_PRODUCT_CODE           = 'product';
    const ENTITY_PRODUCT_REVIEW_CODE    = 'product_review';
    const ENTITY_REVIEW_CODE            = 'review';

    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('rating/rating');
    }

    public function addOptionVote($optionId, $entityPkValue)
    {
        Mage::getModel('rating/rating_option')->setOptionId($optionId)
            ->setRatingId($this->getId())
            ->setReviewId($this->getReviewId())
            ->setEntityPkValue($entityPkValue)
            ->addVote();
        return $this;
    }

    public function updateOptionVote($optionId)
    {
        Mage::getModel('rating/rating_option')->setOptionId($optionId)
            ->setVoteId($this->getVoteId())
            ->setReviewId($this->getReviewId())
            ->setDoUpdate(1)
            ->addVote();
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * retrieve rating options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getOptions()

    {
        if ($options = $this->getData('options')) {
            return $options;
        }
        elseif ($id = $this->getId()) {
            return Mage::getResourceModel('rating/rating_option_collection')
               ->addRatingFilter($id)
               ->setPositionOrder()
               ->load()
               ->getItems();
        }
        return array();

    }


    public function getEntitySummary($entityPkValue,  $onlyForCurrentStore = true)
    {
        $this->setEntityPkValue($entityPkValue);
        return $this->_getResource()->getEntitySummary($this, $onlyForCurrentStore);
    }

    public function getReviewSummary($reviewId,  $onlyForCurrentStore = true)
    {
        $this->setReviewId($reviewId);
        return json_encode($this->_getResource()->getReviewSummary($this, $onlyForCurrentStore));
    var_dump(get_class($this)); //these are the lines added specially
    exit();                      //these two lines(upline also)
    }

    /**
     * Get rating entity type id by code
     *
     * @param string $entityCode
     * @return int
     */
    public function getEntityIdByCode($entityCode)
    {
        return $this->getResource()->getEntityIdByCode($entityCode);
    }
}
```

config.xml file at app/code/local/Mynamespace/Appname/etc/cnfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mynamespace_Appname>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </Mynamespace_Appname>
    </modules>
    <global>
       <models>
          <Appname>
              <rewrite>
                  <item>Mynamespace_Appname_Model_Rating</item>
              </rewrite>
          </Appname>
       </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

File in app/etc/modules/Mynamespace_Appname.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mynamespace_Appname>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Mynamespace_Appname>
    </modules>
</config>
```

In the admin panel it shows module activated..but I didnt find the correct url to run the model file .. **Do I need to create a view file for this???**

can anyone help me on this... If there are any errors in this, please mention them..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Change your class name to:  `class Mynamespace_Appname_Model_Rating`

Make sure your file paths match the cases too (i.e. myname vs Myname)

Comment: Sorry.. In the main file it is correct only. Can u say me the url to query the above rating model through this by giving only product id in the url?